# ListView disappearing after getting data

Tags: android, listview

I have a `Fragment` with a `ListView`. After setting `ListView`'s emptyView everything works ok, but as soon as my adapter (which is extending `BaseAdapter`) gets some data not only emptyView but also whole `Fragment` containing my `ListView` and few other Views disappear.
If I do not use empty view everything works as it should.

Does my adapter need to implement something special for empty view to work? Or it is the way I set emptyView?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_list_view,
(ViewGroup) mListView.getParent());

mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Thank you,

Marcin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out.

I now add empty view directly the place it should be in XML and then `setEmptyView` of my `ListView` in Java, and that works like I wanted it to work.

XML:

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/list_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />    
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/empty_view"          
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="@string/empty_list_view" />
```

and Java part, setting emptyView:

```
View emptyView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

`Adapter` should implement isEmpty():

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty()
{
   return listItems.size() == 0;
}
```

I hope it will help someone in the future. ;)